Simulated / Fake Webmail UI for eudcational purpose
I'm looking for a webapp, that looks and feels like a common webmail UI, but instead of being connected to a real IMAP and SMTP server, it should just display some predefined mails in the inbox.
The background is, that I want my students to look at a set of emails and analyze their legitimacy or maliciousness. Ideally, it would be read-only, such that students can't delete messages and I could easily import messages from .eml or similar. I'm pretty flexible in hosting / server infrastructure to self-host a solution, but I would like to avoid coding my own webapp if something existing can be used.

Hello, that has no real world use except some rare demonstrations like yours, I extremely doubt it exists. I'd simply use some quiz UI with screenshots of topics/messages/headers to ask for validity.

Take a look at https://github.com/maildev/maildev/ maybe it suits your needs?
